# installed ubuntu-desktop in kubuntu but it's not like a new ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, unity, effects

i intalled kubuntu 10.01, then ugraded to kubuntu 12.04 then after a while i used `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` in order to have a desktop environment just like a brand new installed ubuntu 12.04, but some of nice visual effects-like workspace switcher or messages about connecting to a network or a vpn connection establishing or failing that show in the top right of screen and they blur when mouse hovers them....- do not show as they should and they're so much simpler :|

Comment: You probably need  graphics card drivers.

Comment: oh! looks like i'm running unity 2D :| !! i have a powerful graphic card !